# Console log the value of item in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have this array and I want to console log `item` value. How can I do that? I got this array from MongoDB. I would appreciate any help.

```js
{
"_id" : "61462a7bf3c0be993bcfdc3e",
"item": "journal",
"qty": 25,
"size": {
"h": 14,
"w": 21,
"uom": "cm"
},
"status": "A"
}
```

Edit:
I looked in MongoDB documentation and found the solution. Thanks to  everyone who answered.

Comment: What have you tried? What was the result? Why did the result not satisfy your requirements? What have you tried to solve that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can simply access the key from the object like this:

```js
const obj = {
"_id" : "61462a7bf3c0be993bcfdc3e",
"item": "journal",
"qty": 25,
"size": {
"h": 14,
"w": 21,
"uom": "cm"
},
"status": "A"
}

console.log(obj.item);
```

Another way could be to find out the keys and iterate over them if keys are dynamic in nature:

```js
const obj = {
"_id" : "61462a7bf3c0be993bcfdc3e",
"item": "journal",
"qty": 25,
"size": {
"h": 14,
"w": 21,
"uom": "cm"
},
"status": "A"
}

const keys = Object.keys(obj);

keys.forEach(key => console.log(`Key is ${key} and the value is ${JSON.stringify(obj[key])}`))
```

Comment: There's no need to use optional chaining in that first example because you know `obj` exists.

Comment: The user didn't specify any schema which says the `item` will always exist. So, I thought to include it tho it is not needed if it does.

Comment: But that checks for the existence of `obj`, and you already know it exists because you defined it.

Comment: made the change, thank you for correction.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
Object.entries(YOUR_OBJECT_NAME).filter(val=>val[0] === "item")
```

You will get back an array of key and value pair. You can then console.log your value.

Easier solution is that you directly determine your key. If you know what is the name of your key then you can do:

```
console.log(YOUR_OBJECT_NAME.item)
```